# mysqli_connect not defined in Docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mysqli, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and trying to create an image with PHP and MySQL (specifically mysqli).

When I start my app and the PHP code tries to extract from the database, this error comes up:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./public_html:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
```

When I look at `phpinfo()`, there is a section for `mysqlnd` but not one for `mysqli`.

Mysql works in general, as `adminer` works - just `mysqli` is not working.

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: With your dockerfile, can't reproduce.

Comment: @atline it works for you?? Ugh, I thought docker was supposed to solve these annoyances. I restarted computer, deleted the image from the Docker UI, then recreated the image (`docker build -t test-app .`), then created the container (`docker-compose up`) but still no luck.

Comment: are those commands right?  i deleted the image from the UI, changed the docker file to use PHP 8, then created the image and container again with the instructions above. In my app when i run `phpinfo()` it still shows PHP version 7.4... why isnt it showing version 8? is there some cache or something?

Answer (score -1):

I think it was not creating a new image as I expected. I figured this out because I:

- deleted the container from the Docker UI (from the "Containers/Apps" tab)
- changed the version of PHP from 7.4 to 8.0 in `Dockerfile`
- recreated the image from the command line (`docker build -t test-app .`)
- started the container (`docker-compose up`)
- opened my app at `localhost:8080/index.php` which was running `phpinfo();`
- it still showed PHP version 7.4, not 8.0 as expected

So this showed that the newest `Dockerfile` (the one with PHP 8.0) wasn't being used. And since I had added `&& docker-php-ext-enable mysqli` to the `Dockerfile` after an initial run, that wasn't being used either. And that is why it worked for @atline first run.

I got it working by doing the following in the Docker UI:

- on the "Containers/Apps" tab stopping and deleting all of the containers
- on the "Images" tab deleting all of the images (none should be left "in use")
- on the "Volumes" tab deleting all of the volumes

Highly likely I'm not understanding the difference between image/container/app, so I'm possibly using the wrong terms above.

Comment: Keep in mind that docker-compose is a separate thing from docker, and does not care what images you've built with `docker build` in the context of a service with a `build` declaration. Use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild the service images.